# MySQL Get records having a time difference with other records

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a MySQL DB table that logs user login and logout activities. 
I need to select all user records who are not logged back in within 20 minutes after logout.

Ex: Table: Log

```
ID | User | Event  | Time
-----------------------------
1  | 1    | LOGIN  | 10:00:00
2  | 2    | LOGIN  | 10:05:00
3  | 3    | LOGIN  | 10:15:00
4  | 1    | LOGOUT | 11:00:00
5  | 3    | LOGOUT | 11:01:00
6  | 2    | LOGIN  | 12:20:00
7  | 2    | LOGOUT | 12:30:00
8  | 1    | LOGIN  | 12:31:00
9  | 2    | LOGIN  | 12:55:00
```

According to this sample table, the users that exceeds the gap by 20 minutes between their logouts and logins must be shown.
User 1 exceeds the 20 minute gap between record 4 and 8
User 2 exceeds the 20 minute gap between record 7 and 9

So this should show

```
ID | User
----------
4  | 1
8  | 1
7  | 2
9  | 2
```

How can I write a query to get this done?

Comment: If you really need to check _every_ login/logout event for this, then your problem is a gaps and islands problem.  This is difficult to solve, especially if you are using MySQL versions earlier than 8.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question:

> I need to select all user records who are not logged back in within 20 minutes after logout.

```
select lo.*
from (select l.*,
             (select min(l2.time)
              from logs l2
              where l2.user = l.user and l2.time > l.time and
                    l2.event = 'LOGIN'
             ) as next_login_time
      from logs l
      where l.event  = 'LOGOUT'
     ) lo
where next_login_time > time + interval 20 minute;
```

Your sample results include login results.  It is unclear how those are defined, based on the question that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be interested in getting *both* rows if they are 20 minutes apart. The following tries to emulate LEAD and LAG:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, (
        SELECT CASE WHEN EVENT = 'LOGOUT' AND main.Event = 'LOGIN' THEN TimeDIFF(main.Time, Time) END
        FROM t AS prev
        WHERE User = main.User AND Time < main.Time
        ORDER BY Time DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS diff_lag, (
        SELECT CASE WHEN EVENT = 'LOGIN' AND main.Event = 'LOGOUT' THEN TimeDIFF(Time, main.Time) END
        FROM t AS next
        WHERE User = main.User AND Time > main.Time
        ORDER BY Time ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS diff_lead
    FROM t AS main
) x
WHERE diff_lag > '00:20:00' OR diff_lead > '00:20:00'
```

Alternatively, try the following approach which seems to work except that it puts both rows together:

```
SELECT *
FROM t AS o
INNER JOIN t AS i ON o.User = i.User AND o.Time < i.Time                    -- join logouts with potential logins
LEFT JOIN t AS x ON o.User = x.User AND o.Time < x.Time AND x.Time < i.Time -- any row present between logout and login
WHERE o.Event = 'LOGOUT' AND i.Event = 'LOGIN' AND x.ID IS NULL AND TIMEDIFF(i.Time, o.Time) > '00:20:00'
```